# Разделитель sep в Python: как вывести указанные строки через разделитель без пробелов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, separator

> Напишите программу, которая считывает строку-разделитель и три строки,
> а затем выводит указанные строки через разделитель.

**Формат входных данных**
На вход программе подаётся строка-разделитель и три строки, каждая на отдельной строке.

**Формат выходных данных**
Программа должна вывести введённые три строки через разделитель.

```py
sep = input()
input1 = input()
input2 = input()
input3 = input()
print(input1,sep,input2,sep,input3)
```

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: Нужно почитать мануал к функции print, там все написано.

Answer (score 3):

`sep` указывается специальным параметром в значениях для `print`.
например:

```
print("a","b","c",sep="^")
```

выведет `a^b^c`. в вашем случае нужно написать

```
print(input1,input2,input3,sep=sep)
```

Answer (score 2):

либо еще можно почитать мануал по `string` методам и сделать так:

```
print(sep.join([input1,input2,input3]))
```